# Strongloop/loopback 4: how to disable authentication for Explorer component over REST?

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, v4l2loopback

I have followed and set up via [@loopback/authentication](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/blob/master/packages/authentication/README.md)
But the authentication is added to sequence.ts for all calls.
I am unable to skip authentication for `Explorer component`

My open source repo: [opencommerce/questionnaire-server](https://github.com/opencommerce/questionnaire-server)

Details:

- [application.ts](https://github.com/opencommerce/questionnaire-server/blob/master/src/application.ts) has

```
    import {BootMixin} from '@loopback/boot';
      import {ApplicationConfig} from '@loopback/core';
      import {
        RestExplorerBindings,
        RestExplorerComponent,
      } from '@loopback/rest-explorer';
      import {RepositoryMixin} from '@loopback/repository';
      import {RestApplication} from '@loopback/rest';
      import {ServiceMixin} from '@loopback/service-proxy';
      import {
        AuthenticationComponent,
        AuthenticationBindings,
      } from '@loopback/authentication';
      import {MyAuthStrategyProvider} from './providers';
      import * as path from 'path';
      import {MySequence} from './sequence';

      export class QuestionnaireApplication extends BootMixin(
        ServiceMixin(RepositoryMixin(RestApplication)),
      ) {
        constructor(options: ApplicationConfig = {}) {
          super(options);

          // Set up the custom sequence
          this.sequence(MySequence);

          // Set up default home page
          this.static('/', path.join(__dirname, '../../public'));

          // Customize @loopback/rest-explorer configuration here
          this.bind(RestExplorerBindings.CONFIG).to({
            path: '/explorer',
          });
          this.component(RestExplorerComponent);

          this.projectRoot = __dirname;

          this.component(AuthenticationComponent);
          this.bind(AuthenticationBindings.STRATEGY).toProvider(
              MyAuthStrategyProvider,
          );

          // Customize @loopback/boot Booter Conventions here
          this.bootOptions = {
            controllers: {
              // Customize ControllerBooter Conventions here
              dirs: ['controllers'],
              extensions: ['.controller.js'],
              nested: true,
            },
          };
        }
      }
```

- [sequence.ts](https://github.com/opencommerce/questionnaire-server/blob/master/src/sequence.ts) has

```
    import {inject} from '@loopback/context';
      import {
        FindRoute,
        InvokeMethod,
        ParseParams,
        Reject,
        RequestContext,
        RestBindings,
        Send,
        SequenceHandler,
      } from '@loopback/rest';
      import {AuthenticationBindings, AuthenticateFn} from '@loopback/authentication';

      const SequenceActions = RestBindings.SequenceActions;

      export class MySequence implements SequenceHandler {
        constructor(
          @inject(SequenceActions.FIND_ROUTE) protected findRoute: FindRoute,
          @inject(SequenceActions.PARSE_PARAMS) protected parseParams: ParseParams,
          @inject(SequenceActions.INVOKE_METHOD) protected invoke: InvokeMethod,
          @inject(SequenceActions.SEND) public send: Send,
          @inject(SequenceActions.REJECT) public reject: Reject,
          @inject(AuthenticationBindings.AUTH_ACTION)
          protected authenticateRequest: AuthenticateFn,
        ) {}

        async handle(context: RequestContext) {
          try {
            const {request, response} = context;
            const route = this.findRoute(request);

            // This is the important line added to the default sequence implementation
            await this.authenticateRequest(request);

            // Authentication successful, proceed to invoke controller
            const args = await this.parseParams(request, route);
            const result = await this.invoke(route, args);
            this.send(response, result);
          } catch (err) {
            this.reject(context, err);
          }
        }
      }
```

Error while accessing `/` .

```
Unhandled error in GET /: 500 Error: The key controller.current.ctor was not bound to any value.
at QuestionnaireApplication.getBinding (/opt/lampp7.2/htdocs/opencommerce/questionnaire-server/node_modules/@loopback/context/dist/src/context.js:225:15)
at RestServer.getBinding (/opt/lampp7.2/htdocs/opencommerce/questionnaire-server/node_modules/@loopback/context/dist/src/context.js:221:33)
at RequestContext.getBinding (/opt/lampp7.2/htdocs/opencommerce/questionnaire-server/node_modules/@loopback/context/dist/src/context.js:221:33)
at RequestContext.getValueOrPromise (/opt/lampp7.2/htdocs/opencommerce/questionnaire-server/node_modules/@loopback/context/dist/src/context.js:260:30)
at resolution_session_1.ResolutionSession.runWithInjection.s (/opt/lampp7.2/htdocs/opencommerce/questionnaire-server/node_modules/@loopback/context/dist/src/resolver.js:73:24)
at value_promise_1.tryWithFinally (/opt/lampp7.2/htdocs/opencommerce/questionnaire-server/node_modules/@loopback/context/dist/src/resolution-session.js:89:53)
at Object.tryWithFinally (/opt/lampp7.2/htdocs/opencommerce/questionnaire-server/node_modules/@loopback/context/dist/src/value-promise.js:162:18)
at Function.runWithInjection (/opt/lampp7.2/htdocs/opencommerce/questionnaire-server/node_modules/@loopback/context/dist/src/resolution-session.js:89:32)
at resolve (/opt/lampp7.2/htdocs/opencommerce/questionnaire-server/node_modules/@loopback/context/dist/src/resolver.js:66:59)
at value_promise_1.resolveList (/opt/lampp7.2/htdocs/opencommerce/questionnaire-server/node_modules/@loopback/context/dist/src/resolver.js:144:16)
at Object.resolveList (/opt/lampp7.2/htdocs/opencommerce/questionnaire-server/node_modules/@loopback/context/dist/src/value-promise.js:135:32)
at resolveInjectedArguments (/opt/lampp7.2/htdocs/opencommerce/questionnaire-server/node_modules/@loopback/context/dist/src/resolver.js:128:28)
at Object.instantiateClass (/opt/lampp7.2/htdocs/opencommerce/questionnaire-server/node_modules/@loopback/context/dist/src/resolver.js:37:27)
at Binding._getValue (/opt/lampp7.2/htdocs/opencommerce/questionnaire-server/node_modules/@loopback/context/dist/src/binding.js:338:50)
at resolution_session_1.ResolutionSession.runWithBinding.s (/opt/lampp7.2/htdocs/opencommerce/questionnaire-server/node_modules/@loopback/context/dist/src/binding.js:189:90)
at value_promise_1.tryWithFinally (/opt/lampp7.2/htdocs/opencommerce/questionnaire-server/node_modules/@loopback/context/dist/src/resolution-session.js:69:53)
```

Comment: Normally, you shouldn't have issues if you don't put the decorator Strategy on your endpoint. Could you post the code of your controller?

Comment: Sure I'll add the whole code today.

Comment: @angelwally I have added my github repo. Its the project in generated with `lb4`.

Comment: I don't see any controller with the path /. Do you have one?

Comment: https://github.com/opencommerce/questionnaire-server/blob/master/src/application.ts 
`this.component(RestExplorerComponent);`
It handles the `/` path and renders a swagger ui for the API.

But when I add the authentication as in 
https://github.com/opencommerce/questionnaire-server/blob/master/src/sequence.ts
`await this.authenticateRequest(request);`results in exception as above.

Comment: Hi @angelwally I have updated the question with complete details. Please review,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your custom sequence does not skip the authentication for static route `/`.
It can be skipped auth as below:

```
if (!(route instanceof StaticAssetsRoute)) {
  // do your login stuff here
}
```

Now the updated `sequence.ts` will be:

```
import {inject} from '@loopback/context';
import {
  FindRoute,
  InvokeMethod,
  ParseParams,
  Reject,
  RequestContext,
  RestBindings,
  Send,
  SequenceHandler,
  StaticAssetsRoute,
} from '@loopback/rest';
import {AuthenticationBindings, AuthenticateFn} from '@loopback/authentication';

const SequenceActions = RestBindings.SequenceActions;

export class MySequence implements SequenceHandler {
  constructor(
    @inject(SequenceActions.FIND_ROUTE) protected findRoute: FindRoute,
    @inject(SequenceActions.PARSE_PARAMS) protected parseParams: ParseParams,
    @inject(SequenceActions.INVOKE_METHOD) protected invoke: InvokeMethod,
    @inject(SequenceActions.SEND) public send: Send,
    @inject(SequenceActions.REJECT) public reject: Reject,
    @inject(AuthenticationBindings.AUTH_ACTION)
    protected authenticateRequest: AuthenticateFn,
  ) {}

  async handle(context: RequestContext) {
    try {
      const {request, response} = context;
      const route = this.findRoute(request);

      // This is the important line added to the default sequence implementation
      if (!(route instanceof StaticAssetsRoute)) {
        await this.authenticateRequest(request);
      }

      // Authentication successful, proceed to invoke controller
      const args = await this.parseParams(request, route);
      const result = await this.invoke(route, args);
      this.send(response, result);
    } catch (err) {
      this.reject(context, err);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `StaticAssetsRoute` was removed, can you update your answer?

Answer (score 1):

One possible issue you can have is that you bind the values after setting your sequence. Then the bindings does not exist when Loopback tries to resolve them. You should put something more like this:

```
      this.bind(RestExplorerBindings.CONFIG).to({
        path: '/explorer',
      });
      this.component(RestExplorerComponent);

      this.component(AuthenticationComponent);
      this.bind(AuthenticationBindings.STRATEGY).toProvider(
          MyAuthStrategyProvider,
      );

      this.sequence(MySequence);
```

Comment: Thanks but it didnt work.
Anything else I need can try?

Comment: I tried your code, but there is no route for `/`. The one you're talking about is `/explorer`.

Comment: Thanks for efforts.
Just comment out the line `await this.authenticateRequest(request);` from `sequence.ts` and you'll see that `/` route is  rendering a default html page i.e `this.static('/', path.join(__dirname, '../../public'));` in `application.ts `.

Comment: Can you try above?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the following to determine if the route is static.

```
private static isStaticRoute(route: ResolvedRoute): boolean {
  return route.path.search(/^\/explorer\/*/) === 0;
}
```